# How can I get rid of the SetApp folder in my Shared folder on Mac?

Tags: macos

When I try to remove the SetApp folder in my Shared folder, it simply reappears again... What can I do?

Comment: Did you install software from https://setapp.com?

Comment: @JamesBrickley I did. I also tried to uninstall it.

Comment: https://support.setapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/213588369-Uninstalling-Setapp-and-applications - Also contact them support@setapp.com